# Div's margin-top stays 20px when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I want the div on the right side of this [page](http://www.halogamertags.com/dachs) to stop scrolling up when you scroll down the page. So that it is always 20px from the top of the window and the customer can read it's contents.

How can I achieve that? CSS? jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.  Do an on scroll event, and when scroll height gets *past* a certain point, make the div position:fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't the scroll height change for different people?

Comment: yeah, sorry I should have said 'scroll position'... you can see the amount of page that has been scrolled above the top of the window.  http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: This is not working constantly for me.. `$(document).scroll(function () {
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 356){
    $('#rightShipping').css({'position' : 'fixed'});
   }
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 1200){
    $('#rightShipping').css({'position' : 'fixed'});
   }
   console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  });`

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do with the two different ones, but your problem is that you are using == instead of >=.  On scroll might never return EXACTLY 356 or 1200, so you want to have it look at a whole range.